# Advenced custom fields auto fill problem

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I need help. I am using advanced custom fields and by using them i am making a new post. But something went wrong when i enter the site where are my end forms there is filled out information. If i enter a new user there are the same information in those forms. Can someone help me ? Maybe something have stuck in my data base ? I am using this code to create new post.

code here 2x files. http://pastebin.com/4yRRy9Nv

Answer (score -1):

Ok, fixed. I changed `'post_id' => 'new'` to `'post_id' => 'rand()'`. It's working but dont know it shout be like that. Can someone that know php check the code ?

Comment: I haven't tested this but I am having a hard time understanding how this would work. Can you explain?

Comment: s_ha_dum well i have paid a guy to do a end form in my wordpress where users can add post as subsciber and the post save to draft. All fields are used in advenced custom fields plugin. But i had a problem when someone added a post something broke up and new users had old filed up fields insteed of new ones.

I have read here: http://old.support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/3218/front-end-form-help/p1

i shood change new to random() but i am not a php genius maybe i did it wrong but it working